# Left justified table captions with threeparttable and chemstyle

Tags: tables, captions, alignment, threeparttable, chemstyle

First post here, be gentle. I have a problem that I already spent countless hours on. I am a Latex newbie, so this is taking me longer than it should.

I want to align a caption on the left with a table, but the table to be centered. This should be very easily done with threeparttable. But it doesn't work. While creating an MWE for you guys I found out that it works until I load the chemstyle package. If I comment it out, it works like it should. Probably because this in turn loads the float package? Can somebody give me an easy fix on how to solve the issue?
Thank you so much!

```
\documentclass[version, 12pt, USenglish, a4paper, parskip=full]{scrbook}

\usepackage[varioref=false]{chemstyle} %also loads chemscheme, psfrags, xspace, amstext, caption, float, kvoptions, siunitx or SIunits 

% TABLES: 
\usepackage{booktabs}   
\usepackage{multirow}   
\usepackage{makecell}   
\usepackage{caption} 
\captionsetup[table]{singlelinecheck=false, justification=justified}
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
    \centering
    \label{tab:binding-energies}
    \begin{threeparttable}
        \caption{Exemplary table text: Very very long caption, so very very very long. Oh long John. Long looooooong maaaaaaaaaan.}
        \begin{tabular}{@{}l|l@{}}
            \toprule
            Column one              & Column two\tnote{1}         \\ \midrule
            bbbbb bbbb              & 200--300   bli bla          \\
            cccccccccccc ccccccc    & 50--200 yadda yadda yadda   \\ \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}
        \begin{tablenotes}
            \item[1] Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet who am I kidding I dont know how to continue this fake text and I am too lazy to copy it from the web.
        \end{tablenotes}
    \end{threeparttable}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Which functionalities of the `chemstyle` package are you especially interested in for your document?

Comment: Entirely unrelated to the issue but please be aware that a `\label` must be placed after the corresponding `\caption`otherwise the number retunred by `\ref` will not fit.

Comment: Right, I misplaced the label, oups. Until you asked, I thought I need the chemstyle package, but actually, I might not. Schemes can be added by chemscheme, for SI units I now use siunitx... I might just disable it and see if I miss anything thats hard to workaround, if nothing else comes up.

Comment: Okay, apparently it is the "chemscheme" part thats interfering. And I really need to label some pictures "schemes" instead of "figures". I reather have the table captions misformatted instead of not using that package, I think.

Comment: Take a lok at the `chemmacros` package and its `scheme` module.

Comment: I did and that seems to solve the problem... I can create schemes and compound numbering with chemnum still seems to work. So I'll do the switch from chemstyles to chemmacros, alright. Good thing I did this early on... If you add that as an answer I will do whatever is done on this page with right answers :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you used the `chemstyle` bundle in order to get access to the `scheme` float that can be used for reaction schemes, I suggest switching to `chemmacros` and its `scheme` module instead. Captions in a `threeparttable` are still as wide as the table if `chemmacros` is loaded:

[image]

```
\documentclass[version, 12pt, USenglish, a4paper, parskip=full]{scrbook}

\usepackage{chemmacros}
\usechemmodule{scheme}

% TABLES: 
\usepackage{booktabs}   
\usepackage{multirow}   
\usepackage{makecell}   
\usepackage{caption} 
\captionsetup[table]{singlelinecheck=false, justification=justified}
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
    \centering
    \label{tab:binding-energies}
    \begin{threeparttable}
        \caption{Exemplary table text: Very very long caption, so very very very long. Oh long John. Long looooooong maaaaaaaaaan.}
        \begin{tabular}{@{}l|l@{}}
            \toprule
            Column one              & Column two\tnote{1}         \\ \midrule
            bbbbb bbbb              & 200--300   bli bla          \\
            cccccccccccc ccccccc    & 50--200 yadda yadda yadda   \\ \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}
        \begin{tablenotes}
            \item[1] Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet who am I kidding I dont know how to continue this fake text and I am too lazy to copy it from the web.
        \end{tablenotes}
    \end{threeparttable}
\end{table}


\begin{scheme}
\caption{reaction scheme}
\end{scheme}
\end{document}
```